# Back button not working in browsers

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser

I recently switched from Windows to Ubuntu. The back buttons in the browsers (both firefox *and* chrome) are not working. 
Every time I have to right click and select 'back' option.

Is there any work around for this?

Comment: That sounds suspicious. The backbutton in firefox and opera works for me.

Comment: Are you talking about the Back button in the browser or your multimedia keyboard?

Comment: Like Lekensteyn asks, or the Backspace key?

Comment: Like Lekensteyn and JanC ask, or a special button on your mouse?

Comment: Like Lekensteyn and JanC and MichaelMS ask, or the button that is (or supposely should be) in the upper-left corner of the screen?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firefox: navigate to **about:config** then set **browser.backspace_action** to **0**

Chrome: install the [Backspace Shortcuts for Linux](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/aeffggjddcchloadflonilaahpclmbnm) extension and setup

Source: [Backspace vs Firefox & Chromium @ Falu.Me](http://falu.me/2011/03/28/backspace-vs-firefox-chromium)

Comment: It worked for me to use `backspace` key to go back.

Answer (score 2):

This didn’t work for me.

However going to **`about:config`** and changing value of **`browser.sessionhistory.max_entries`** to **`100`** (was **`0`** earlier) and restarting Firefox does the magic.

Answer (score 1):

Type `about:config` in the address bar in the browser.

Find `browser.sessionhistory.max_total_viewer`

Right click & choose "Reset"